# Rendering artifacts with linear interpolation in gdal_grid

Tags: gdal, gdal-grid

I have problems with strange artifacts occuring when rendering GeoTIFFs using `gdal_grid` with the `linear` interpolation algorithm.

#### Input files

I have a `samples.csv` file with some geo data samples:

```
latitude,longitude,value
53.8035355,17.020874,19.43
53.803688,17.0284729,19.36
53.8038445,17.0360718,19.38
53.8040047,17.0436707,19.38
53.8041649,17.0513,19.45
53.8043213,17.0588989,19.47
53.8044815,17.0664978,19.55
...
```

For this data, I created a simple `samples.vrt` file:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="samples">
    <SrcDataSource>samples.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="longitude" y="latitude" z="value" />
  </OGRVRTLayer>
```

I also have a `colormap` file for the data (for use with `gdaldem`):

```
-9999.0 0:0:0:0
-28 245:245:245:255
-26 235:235:235:255
-24 225:225:225:255
-22 190:190:190:255
-20 130:130:130:255
...
```

I uploaded the input files [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Am4ja3-9W8mUj7V1piomo2OknwBDsQ).

#### Procedure

First, I create a GeoTIFF with `gdal_grid`:

```
gdal_grid \
  -ot Float64 \
  -of GTiff \
  -txe 16.870876 19.691624 \
  -tye 54.980014 53.746311 \
  -outsize 682 512 \
  -a linear:radius=0.0:nodata=-9999.0 \
  samples.vrt samples.tiff
```

Then I colorize the tiff with `gdaldem`:

```
gdaldem \
  color-relief \
  samples.tiff colormap samples-colored.tiff
```

#### Result

If I use the `linear` interpolation algorithm, I get the following result:

(Notice the red bars at the top.)

[image]

If I switch to the `nearest` algorithm, e.g.

```
-a nearest:radius1=0.01:radius2=0.01:nodata=-9999.0
```

the output image looks fine:

[image]

It is also fine if I use the `linear` algorithm, but flip the image by specifying `-tye` in the reverse order, i.e. `-tye 53.746311 54.980014` - so maybe the problem is somehow related to the negative pixel dimensions.

In my tests, I used GDAL 2.3.0.